# Android 2.3.3 | How to Make Spinner Just Display Information and Not Allow User to See Options

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner that I want to be editable or interactable with some users and just used to view information for other users? Is there a way to make a Spinner to display information that I would have already preselected in the background.

Comment: What would the advantage be of this versus just a plain `TextView`?

Answer (score 6):

In your xml you can simply add this line to the Spinner item:

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Then you can display the information you like, but it is not clickable. If you need to do this programmatically you can just use this line of code:

```
mySpinner.setClickable(false);
```

And just in case you need to know how to show certain information:

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner) spinnerlayout.findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
        //Here you set the String array to use
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this, R.array.STRING_ARRAY_USED, R.layout.spinner); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mySpinner.setClickable(false);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mySpinner.setSelection(HERE YOU SET THE INDEX OF THE ARRAY ITEM TO SHOW);
        mySpinner
                .setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```